# OAuth Endpoint in Sandbox

Tags: rest-api, oauth2

Usually I use https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token as my Login Endpoint connecting via REST Api. Now a friend of mine created a Sandbox and I was wondering what the aquivalent URL is here, since using the one above I get an authorization error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as usual, istead of `login` for production use `test` for sandbox.

---

[Understanding OAuth Endpoints](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_oauth_endpoints.htm) article confirms it.

> If you’re verifying authentication on a sandbox organization, use
>   “test.salesforce.com” instead of “login.salesforce.com” in all the
>   OAuth endpoints listed above.

```
https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
```